# How does one add false colour to a fits image

Tags: exposure

I have an exposure of a star field with a small galaxy located near the centre. It is of course a greyscale image. I would like to add colours (realistic) to this image for aesthetic purposes. What software can I use to play around with colours that is Linux compatible and relatively easy to get the hang of? I've been using DS9 which has some colour options but to my knowledge doesn't quite produce a realistic colour image.

Comment: I hurts advertising for IDL, and I'm sure you can find better ways in Python (or something else), but I previously used IDL's [tctool](http://idlastro.gsfc.nasa.gov/ftp/contrib/malumuth/tctool.pro).

Comment: To add "realistic" colour requires that you have exposures of the same field through different filters (at least two, preferably 3)